# Can you call multiple methods on one line?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For example I would like to:

```
texta = text.lower()
textacopy1 = texta.replace(string.punctuation, ' ')
textacopy2 = textacopy1.split(' ')
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this without having to assign multiple variables?

If there is a difference between 2.7 and 3.x I would prefer the 3.x explanation.

Comment: By the way, as far as I can tell, `replace(string.punctuation, ' ')` probably does not do what you want. You have to call it for all the individual characters contained in `punctuation`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, that was a problem I fixed with a loop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
result = text.lower().replace(string.punctuation, ' ').split(' ')
```

With great python comes great responsibility: don't abuse this feature!

The canonical maximum line length codified in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) is 80 characters,
and the canonical way to split a method chain is start new lines at a dot:

```
result = text.lower().replace(string.punctuation, ' ')
        .split(' ')
```

Comment: Nice touch with dot - did not know that

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with one variable you don't have to use multiple variable which can cause confusion. Also code will be much cleaner. You can do it in one line also.

```
text = text.lower()
text = text.replace(string.punctuation, ' ')
text = text.split(' ')
```

Also you can do it in one line

```
text = text.lower().replace(string.punctuation, ' ').split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions, it's even cleaner

```
    In [132]: split_str = re.compile(r'[{} ]+'.format(string.punctuation))

    In [133]: split_str.split("You can do it with one variable you don't have to use multiple variable which can cause confusion. Also code will be much cleaner. You can do it in one line also.")
    Out[133]: 
    ['You',
     'can',
     'do',
     'it',
.....
     'in',
     'one',split_string = 
     'line',
     'also',
     '']
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is - it works with immutable objects, for e.g. with strings because every call returns a new object.

```
'Hello'.lower().replace('ell', '') # 'ho'
```

But it may not work with mutable objects, like lists, dicts, user-defined objects, because these methods, in general, return None.

```
{1: 'chicken', 2: 'duck'}.update({3: 'goose'}) # None
#                         dict gets lost here
```

So I came up with a solution.

Take mutable object  > Execute methods  > Return object.

```
a = take([1, 2, 3]).append(4).extend([5, 6]).unwrap()
# a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

b = take({1: 'chicken', 2: 'duck'}).update({3: 'goose'}).update({4: 'moose'}).unwrap()
# b = {1: 'chicken', 2: 'duck', 3: 'goose', 4: 'moose'}
```

Code:

```
class take:
    class mockmeth:
        def __init__(self, name, taken):
            self.name = name
            self.bounded = getattr(taken.obj, name)
            self.taken = taken

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.bounded(*args, **kwargs)
            return self.taken

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.mockmeth(name, self)

    def unwrap(self):
        return self.obj
```

Github rep: https://github.com/phantie/one-line_methods